# The correct way to manipulate doubles on MYSQL (precision)?

Tags: mysql

I have a 1-cent-auction website that increases bids by 1 cent on every bid

The `current_bid` field is a DOUBLE on mysql that represents the bid in dollars, and i need to avoid cases like 0.2 + 0.1 = 0.299999999
(not sure if it's the right result format but you get the idea)

I have had lots of cases other than with these two numbers because of precision..

Now, here is my code : (i am hoping its correct and efficient, otherwise, i am open to your ideas)

```
UPDATE `auctions` SET 
`current_bid` = ROUND(ROUND(`current_bid` * 100) + 1)/100
...
```

Comment: What's your problem? Do you need `10.22` or `0.30` in this formate number?

Comment: i need the current_bid to increase by 0.01, so the format (as i said) is in dollars : X.XX but the problem is that sometimes, because of precision i get weird numbers if i remove the ROUND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it too late to switch to [DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fixed-point-types.html)? [Floating point](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html) column types provide approximate values; it's a well known fact and it's by design.